# Let the user to download video/audio file only by password

Tags: php, mysql

I try to create the shop where user could buy the video/audio files. The files will be placed at another remote server (Debian). I can't figure out how to let downloading for particular user only. I could calculate the control sum somehow by IP and the link will be something like this:

http://100.000.000.000/files/video.avi?hash=87a686d86d8868a6868a

But how to check this on the remote server? I don't know is the good idea to read whole movie file with PHP script.

Comment: Use `md5_file()` to calculate the hash without reading the whole file into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically two methods are possible.

**File system:**

You could use the file system, create a password protected folder for each user and copy all their files to it, or better, if you use Linux, use symbolic links (ln -s).

**PHP:**

Or you could stream files through PHP while it checks access. I don't think that's a real problem. PHP doesn't need to do much if it just pushes through raw data.

```
$total     = filesize($filepath);
$blocksize = (2 << 20); //2M chunks
$sent      = 0;
$handle    = fopen($filepath, "r");

// Push headers that tell what kind of file is coming down the pike
header('Content-type: '.$content_type);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
header('Content-length: '.$filesize*1024);

// Now we need to loop through the file and echo out chunks of file data
// Dumping the whole file fails at > 30M!
while($sent < $total) {
  echo fread($handle, $blocksize);
  $sent += $blocksize;
}
```

(code is short, no error checks, no password check, no file closure, etc)

It does depend on what kind of password system you have, and what you're allowed to do on your server.

Comment: The second method seems more appropriate for me. Could you tell me how  to do this with PHP? I can't imagine how to give 2Gb file to user, I thought it will be not enough RAM memory to read it.

Comment: You stream it to the user, there's no need to have it all in memory. See, for instance: http://teddy.fr/2007/11/28/how-serve-big-files-through-php and see: http://www.media-division.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php